How to prevent breakable tcolorbox ending up on next page without breaking?
I am having a problem with a tcolorbox directly under a heading, which is moved to the next page instead of breaking. This only occurs for very specific heights of the box. Also I've only been able to reproduce it with the KOMA document class not the standard report class, but to be fair that might just be because I didn't try hard enough. I'm wondering whether this is normal behavior (and how to prevent it) or whether this is an actual bug and I should submit an issue. In that case I'm not sure where to submit the issue KOMA or tcolorbox.
A minimal working example:
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title={#1}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{Test}

\begin{mybox}{title}
    \lipsum[1-4][1-61]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}

Output:


You could use the ignore nobreak key, or enlarge the page a bit:
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title={#2},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\section{Test}

\begin{mybox}[ignore nobreak]{title}
    \lipsum[1-4][1-61]
\end{mybox}

\chapter{test}

\section{Test}\enlargethispage{0.2\baselineskip}

\begin{mybox}{title}
    \lipsum[1-4][1-61]
\end{mybox}


\end{document}



ignore nobreak key? It's almost as if you had looked at the documentation. I guess I'll delete my answer
